# I killed Amata's father and now she won't talk to me

Tags: fallout-3

When you are escaping the vault in the beginning, I need to recover the password to open the secret tunnel. On my way to the Overseer's office, I came across a room where my friend, Amata, was being interrogated by her father, The Overseer, and a guard. After I killed the guard, I talked to The Overseer, but I always ended up killing him in order to get the password, and then Amata gets mad at me.

Is there any other way to get the codes or to escape?

Comment: Oh Arqade titles... Y U SO RANDOM?^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can find keys in lockers around the room you confront him.  Grab the keys to the office and you can then unlock the Vault door.

There is a wiki page which has more details on how to escape.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Escape!